# breqn with superscript in a newcommand

Tags: breqn

I am getting unfortunate behavior with the the most recent version of `breqn.sty` with regards to how it handles a `newcommand` that begins with a superscript.  Considering the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\newcommand{\hc}{^\dagger}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
  A\hc
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

This code will not stop compiling, and hangs on this error:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \penalty 
l.6   A\hc

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.7 \end{dmath}
```

(Note that older iterations of `breqn.sty` did not give me this issue.)

However, if I just replace `\hc` with `^\dagger`, everything works. Also, if I replace `dmath` with any of the standard math environments, it works (I've been using this particular `newcommand` for years).

Is it bad practice to have a superscript begin a `newcommand`? Is there a way to modify my `\hc` to make the above code just work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way `breqn` works is rather complex, and so I'm not surprised that it fails in the case you give. I'd suggest sticking rigidly to the formally-allowed syntax for superscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\newcommand{\hc}{^{\dagger}}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
  A\hc
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

---

As Bruno observes, this is to do with category codes. The following also works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\catcode`\^=12 %
\newcommand{\hc}{^\dagger}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
  A\hc
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

as `breqn` makes `^` an 'other' character.

which works fine.

Comment: I strongly suspect that it has to do with the catcode of `^` being set to active by breqn `\AtBeginDocument`. Can't test at the moment, though.

Answer (score 4):

To complement Joseph's answer and Bruno's comment, here's some analysis of the situation.

**breqn** changes all mathcodes to `"8000` so that characters in math mode behave like macros; and changes also the meaning of commands such as `\dagger`.

The meanings of `^`, `A` and `\dagger` become

```
> ^=macro:
#1->\mathsup {\protect \subsupstyle #1}.

> A=\protected\long macro:
->\@sym A\math_sym_Var:Nn \mg@Latin {41}.

> \dagger=\protected\long macro:
->\@sym \dagger \math_sym_Bin:Nn \mg@bin {79}.
```

where `\mathsup` is an alias for the usual category 7 `^`.

With `\newcommand{\hc}{^\dagger}` given in the preamble, `^` still has category 7 and such remains when `\hc` is expanded. But an important property of category 7 `^` in math mode is that it keeps expanding the next token until an unexpandable one is found (and it has better be a mathchardef token or a chardef token or a left brace). After a good deal of expansions, in the present case `^` is presented `\penalty`, which is not a good token after it.

The safest definition would be

```
\begingroup\lccode`?=`^
  \lowercase{\endgroup\newcommand{\hc}{?{\dagger}}}
```

or

```
{\catcode`^=12 \gdef\hc{^{\dagger}}}
```

as changing at that point the catcode of `^` could be dangerous. Maybe issuing

```
\catcode`^=12
\newcommand{\hc}{^{\dagger}}
```

just before `\begin{document}` may not have unexpected consequences. In any case, defining `\hc` with a catcode 7 `^` should be avoided, as it can interfere with the workings of **breqn**: there's quite a difference between

```
\mathsup{\protect\subsupstyle \dagger}
```

and

```
\mathsup{\dagger}
```

The latter is what LaTeX would see with the catcode 7 `^` definition.