# Multiple tensor indices with breqn package

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, breqn

When I try to use the `tensor` style file to create multiple tensor indices with the `breqn` style file, I run into the following problem shown in this (minimal) code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
$\tensor{F}{_a}$
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Package tensor Error: Sub/Superscript items out of order on input line 5, 

--- TeX said ---
(tensor)                some index tokens may now have been lost.

See the tensor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 $\tensor{F}{_a}
                   $
--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

An index string has an extra or missing `^' or `_' token.
```

I suspect this has to do with how `breqn.sty` redefines `^` and `_` as the user [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) talked about [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31414/5050). If I take out the `breqn` package, everything compiles nicely.

My question is: Is there something I can put in the preamble or elsewhere to return functionality to the `\tensor` command while still using the `breqn` package?

**OR**

Is there something I can use that is *not* the `tensor.sty` style file to create tensors like
`\tensor[^{ab}_c]{F}{_{def}^g_h}` which would produce something that looks like this:

[image]

while still using the `breqn.sty` package?

Comment: I have a feeling that you may be out of luck on this one. You may want to send an email to the maintainer of the breqn package and ask him for advice.

Comment: I modified the question to make it not as narrow, hopefully that'll help my "luck" on this one. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `breqn` package plays around with category codes of the subscript and superscript characters, but it only sets them at the `\begin{document}`. What we need is to set them earlier, before `\usepackage{tensor}`. For instance, the following appears to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\catcode`_=12
\catcode`^=12
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
$\tensor[^{ab}_c]{F}{_{def}^g_h}$
\end{document}
```

Also, `breqn` seems to have a bug: it leaves `_` with category code 11 rather than 8 or 12. (But you don't need to worry about that.)

Comment: Given my previous question, I should have been able to figure this out. Thanks, @bruno.  My only comment would be what you've all but said explicitly: To make sure the ``\catcode`_=12 \catcode`^=12 \usepackage{tensor}`` part is as close to the `\begin{document}` as possible since doing this can mess up other packages (personally, I ran into problems with the `verbatim.sty` package being called after the `\catcode`'s)

Comment: Good point about keeping catcode assignments as late as possible.

Comment: Better yet, @bruno, would it be OK to just call ``\catcode`_=12 \catcode`^=12 \usepackage{tensor} \catcode`_=8 \catcode`^=7`` so that packages after the tensor package will still try to function normally? Or is there something wrong with this?

Comment: @thequark: the only drawback to what you propose is that it introduces more code. Otherwise, no problem.

Comment: @Bruno: I didn't pry into the code of `breqn`, it seems quite complex. I wonder why it sets the catcode of `_` and `^` at `\begin{document}`. It works fine if I use `\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8}` after `\usepackage{breqn}`, and then I can use `\usepackage{tensor}` before it.

Comment: @LeoLiu: `breqn` loads `mathstyle`, and making sub and supscripts of catcode other allows to make them active in math mode, to add some code keeping track of the current style (that's not possible in plain TeX because of primitives such as `\over`, which change the style of previous stuff on the math list...). Now, tracking the math style is useful to avoid needing the expensive typesetting of `\mathchoice`.

Comment: @Bruno: OK. For compatibility with other package, I would rather use `mathstyleoff` option even it is more expensive. But the catcode bug for `_` of `breqn` should still be fixed. I'll send a email to Morten Høgholm.

Comment: @LeoLiu: it seems that `\breqnpopcats` is the culprit: it is trying to restore the catcode of `_`, but it picks up the "current value" at the wrong time. I think that `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are doing their job correctly here, and simply removing `\breqnpopcats` altogether may fix it. Joseph pointed out to me in chat that the breqn doc has the relevant address to report bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could use the [tensind](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tensind) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{tensind}

\tensordelimiter{?}

\begin{document}

$?{}^{ab}_c?$$?F_{def}^{}^g_h?$

\begin{dmath}
  f(x)=\frac{1}{x} \condition*{x\neq 0}.
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is `mathstyle` package (included by `flexisym`, and `flexisym` is included by `breqn`) which messes the catcodes of `_` and `^`. You can use (undocumented) `mathstyleoff` option to turn it off. It seems that `mathstyle` package does nothing to do with the main purpose of `breqn`, but I'm not sure.

Since you use `[mathstyleoff]` option of `breqn`, you can use `\usepackage{tensor}` before or after `breqn` package.

But as Bruno said, it is a bug that the catcode of `_` remains 11 after `breqn`, since `expl3` and `\ProvidesExplPackage` makes `_` to be a letter. Therefore you should use `` \catcode`\_=8 `` after the package.

This is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage[mathstyleoff]{breqn}
%\catcode`\_=8 % use it for safey

\begin{document}

$\tensor[^{ab}_c]{F}{_{def}^g_h}$

\begin{dmath}
a+b=c=d
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just typeset it manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}% http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*} \mathstrut^{ab}\mathstrut_c F\mathstrut_{def}\mathstrut^g\mathstrut_h \end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

`\mathstrut` stretches to a required vertical length with zero horizontal width. Of course, this takes away from the readability of the code. But this depends to what extent you formerly used `tensor` in your document.